# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting biology research sites
- useful resources for practitioner and student alike
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3521).

Answer (score 9):

[image: bioRxiv]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Inspired by AMR's [post](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/community-promotion-ads-2016/3296#3296).

Comment: Is it same as PubMed Central (PMC) repository? If not, then I would like to   make a separate ad for it.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused It is different, PMC is a database of abstracts and references of biomedical papers. While bookshelf is one for e-books only.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

Comment: With [chemistry.se] SE now two years past graduation, I am wondering whether votes here might be more usefully applied to ads for SE sites that are still in beta like [Genealogy & Family History](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3689/8157) SE.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: I want to give it +10 votes. How can I do that :P :) ?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused You could create a community promotion ad that links to this answer and solicits votes for it ;)

Comment: @BryanKrause  mm... that would be duplicate answer on this same OP . Isn't?

Comment: I just meant it as a joke - to create a second ad to promote the post that proposes creating the original ad. An ad for an ad, if you will.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused ditto - can't upvote this one enough! :)

Answer (score 8):

[image: BioNumbers]

Comment: +1 really cool site! :). How do I not know about this?!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Join Genealogy & Family History SE!]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Google Scholar]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Project Gutenberg: Free Library of Classic Books]

Comment: Some samples: [Insectivorous plants by Charles Darwin](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/5765), [The Voyage of Beagle by C. Darwin](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/944/pg944-images.html), [AncienT Plants by Marie Stopes](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43976), [The chemistry of plant life by Wilfred Thatcher](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33394), Life movements in plants by J.C. Bose Vol [1](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/48280) and [2](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/40050), etc.

Comment: Initially it was posted in com. prom. ad at [2016](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/community-promotion-ads-2016/3489#3489). But it was November 2016, towards end of the year. So it didn't reached to many readers, hence once reposted here.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 3):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 2):

[image: BigBrain]

Comment: Programs used to edit the photoes: 1. MS-paint, 2. MS-office picture manager.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Go Vote Now!]

Comment: Did you draw that?!

Comment: Draw? no. The figures I found online. Compile and format? yes :).

Comment: Are we all going to downvote this in a week?

Comment: @canadianer yes. that or I'll just delete it I guess :p

Comment: @theforestecologist Just a reminder to delete! Though possibly you could repost here and ask not to be upvoted, such that someone could dig it up for a future election?

Comment: Added a space to the [text] to enable down-voting.

Comment: I wouldn't delete it; a few downvotes will do. It's awesome and perhaps of use later :-)

Comment: Sorry for downvoting but just to get it off the main site.

Comment: First and only time I'll ever say it, but: Thanks all for downvoting ;)

Comment: It's 2019. I guess you could all un-downvote now ;p.

Answer (score 0):

[image: March supporting government policy informed by science]

Comment: I hope this doesn't seem like an imposition, as i'm not otherwise a member of this site, but it was suggested that i put up this proposal on the core science site of stack exchange to see if the members wanted to promote the event. If there is a feeling it is political, i want to raise the point that science isn't supposed to be political, only about pursuit of the truth, so this doesn't qualify if you look at it that way.

Comment: If you don't think it belongs here, it has been proposed also for Academia.SE, where it falls within the site's mandate much more clearly. If you are a member there, that post is [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/3692/69922).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Your Guide to Understanding Genetic conditions]